# In Play, is there an easy and elegant way to get the time it takes for a webservice to answer?

Tags: scala, web-services, playframework, future, playframework-2.5

In my play application I call a webservice with `play.api.libs.ws.WSClient`. I would like to know if I could easily retrieve the time it takes for the future to complete, see snippet below ( I know I could measure time before and after but I was hoping for something more robust). Any idea?

```
val request: WSRequest = ws.url(url)
val response:Future[WSResponse] = request.get()

response.map{r =>
  // status
  r.status
  // how can I get the time it took to get the response??
}
```

Comment: I think you can use [request filters](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.5.x/ScalaWS#Request-Filters) to [instrument/trace](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/scala-user/nOPv4Ar-eZc) `Futures`.